# SQL Case statement with multiple actions in then

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am trying to create a SQL case statement where one of the then statement will have multiple actions. Not sure if this is even possible and this part `( @ItemCountVariable = a.ItemCount + 10)` of the below query does not work but this is what I am trying to achieve.

```
DECLARE @ItemCountVariable INT = 0
...

WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET Name = a.Name, 
           [Description] = a.[Description],
           ItemCount =
            (CASE WHEN  ((a.ItemCount + 10) < 20)
                    THEN a.ItemCount + 10
                  ELSE a.ItemCount, @ItemCountVariable = a.ItemCount + 10
            END)
...
```

Comment: Your statement is wrong with missing `END` for `CASE`.  Please describe properly what you wanna do with `@ItemCountVariable = a.ItemCount + 10`.

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement...

Answer (score 2):

As jarlh wrote in his comment, `case` is an expression, not a statement.
This means that case returns a single value, and can not be used as a flow control element.
For more information, here is the relevant qoute from MSDN Official documentation about [`case`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx): (I've bolded the relevant part)

> Remarks
>   SQL Server allows for only 10 levels of nesting in CASE expressions.
>
> **The CASE expression cannot be used to control the flow of execution of Transact-SQL statements, statement blocks, user-defined functions, and stored procedures.** For a list of control-of-flow methods, see [Control-of-Flow Language (Transact-SQL).](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174290.aspx)

Comment: Just as I thought. This is not possible, thanks for the link Zohar.

Answer (score 0):

Go with `BEGIN...END`

```
DECLARE @Iteration Integer = 0;
WHILE @Iteration <10  
BEGIN  
    SELECT FirstName, MiddleName   
    FROM dbo.DimCustomer WHERE LastName = 'Adams';
    SET @Iteration += 1  ;
END;
```